# Java : new Filter(){} to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to make a filter for my RecyclerView , I find how to do that in Java but I want to implement this in Kotlin , this code is placed into Adapter class.

```
private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint , FilterResults results) {}
};
```

How this code can be used for kotlin? Here is the full code for Adapter class https://pastebin.com/a2dj30By

Comment: have you checked this yet? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

Comment: use an adapter that already implements `Filterable` interface

Comment: so why dont you want to use an adapter that already implements `Filterable` interface? why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I watched a tutorial , i'm a beginer

Comment: so extend [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) adapter - here you have some sample [CurrencyAdapter](https://pastebin.com/raw/LEena3pM) - this is a working `Filterable` adapter that shows currency names / symbols

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement this soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private val exampleFilter = object : Filter() {
   override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence): Filter.FilterResults? {
      //TODO do stuff
      return null
   }

   override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: Filter.FilterResults) {
      //TODO do stuff
   }
}
```